# How to pass quoted args to GNU Parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, args

I need to pass some text that includes whitespace and other characters to a script that's being run by GNU Parallel.

Here is a very simple example:

```
$ seq 1 3 | parallel echo "Quoted ' (text)"
```

The above example will output this:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

However, if I do this everything works:

```
seq 1 3 | parallel echo "\"Quoted ' (text)\""
```

I happen to be running this from a python script, so before passing the arguments I'm double quoting them in the script like this:

```
args = ["Some arg", "Another arg", "etc."]
args = ' '.join(pipes.quote(pipes.quote(arg)) for arg in args)
```

But it doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Does anybody know of a better way to pass arguments to GNU Parallel?

Thanks!

Comment: 'not a clean solution', but does it work? Good luck.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
zsh-4.3.12[sysadmin]% print -l {1..3} | 
  parallel -q echo "Quoted ' (text)"
Quoted ' (text) 1
Quoted ' (text) 2
Quoted ' (text) 3
```

As described by @mortehu:

> Arguments passed to commands through parallel are expanded by the shell twice: once in the invocation of parallel, and once when parallel runs your command. `-q` prevents the second shell expansion.

Comment: Thank you! I looked the man page for something so simple but could not find. Thank you for answering so clearly and not saying something like "Read the man page!"  So simple.

Comment: To make this a bit clearer: Arguments passed to commands through parallel are expanded by the shell twice: once in the invocation of parallel, and once when parallel runs your command. `-q` prevents the second shell expansion.

Answer (score 12):

There is a whole section in the man page dedicated to quoting:

http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/man.html#QUOTING

It even mentions the very error messages you write in your question.

If you can write it better please email your version to: parallel@gnu.org.